# runtime error: addition of unsigned offset/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior

Tags: c++, vector, overflow, indexoutofboundsexception

I am not able to find where is my vector going out of bound. This is solution of leetcode question 695.

Error:

> Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x610000000040 overflowed to 0x610000000028 (stl_vector.h)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34

Code:

```
int maxAreaOfIsland(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
    int n = grid.size();
    int m = grid[0].size(); 
    
    vector<vector<int>> vis(n,vector<int>(m,0));
    int ans =0 ;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
            int count  = 0;
            if(grid[i][j]==1 && !vis[i][j]) {
                vis[i][j]=1;
                queue<pair<int,int>> q;
                q.push({i,j});
                count++;
                while(!q.empty()) {
                    int  a = q.front().first;
                    int  b = q.front().second;
                    q.pop();
                    
                    int r[] = {-1, 1, 0, 0};
                    int c[] = {0, 0, 1, -1};
                    
                    for(int z=0; z<4; z++) {
                       int x = a + r[z];
                       int y = b + c[z]; 
                       if(x<n && y<m && grid[x][y]==1 && !vis[x][y]) {
                           vis[x][y]=1;
                           q.push({x,y});
                           count++;
                       }
                    }
                    
                }
                ans = max(ans,count);
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector::at` and you'll find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect

```
if(x<n && y<m && grid[x][y]==1 && !vis[x][y]) {
```

should be

```
if (x>=0 && y>=0 && x<n && y<m && grid[x][y]==1 && !vis[x][y]) {
```

Notice in the error `addition of unsigned offset to 0x610000000040 overflowed to 0x610000000028`. In other words the unsigned offset is negative (when regarded as a signed quantity).

Always be careful mixing signed and unsigned arithmetic.

Comment: my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not able to find where is my vector going out of bound

The simplest way(IMO) to find out where you're going out of bounds in the vector is to use `std::vector::at` instead of `std::vector::operator[]`.

When using `at` you'll get an `out_of_range` exception if the index is greater or equal to the size of the vector. For example, use `grid.at(i).at(j)` instead of `grid[i][j]` and so on for other as well.